# Method of using previous scenes in ending credit

Tags: ending, cinematography

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cbuPISv238&t=5m45s) is the ending credit for the game Final Fantasy 7 Remake. The ending credit uses clips from the cutscenes in the game. I've seen this kind of method of using part of the flim in the ending credit in other movies too. Is there a name for this method?

Comment: Whilst this question could related to TV shows and movies, your example of a game is off-topic (I assume). Do you have an example of one of the former you can update your question with?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not everything has a name, it is what it is: adding scenes from the movie to the credits to make it less dull. Many times I see it taken a step further, they put scenes that were cut from the movie, i.e. the viewer will get to see "new" scenes if they'll watch all the credits. There're no set rules for this, or even a "norm" that's really up to each movie provider and the people behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a **montage** in the end credits.

TV Tropes calls this a [**Credits Montage**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CreditsMontage):

> ### Credits Montage
>
> The credits are rolling! Wasn't that a great show? Let's all reflect
> on the great moments we just watched... ah, here they come now, and
> they brought a stirring, victorious musical track, too!
>
> In short; the credit sequences of TV shows, movies or video games
> include a [montage](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Montage) of stills or clips from earlier in the show.